# How to enable auto-screen update on monitor plug-in/out on Lubuntu (Also, how can this be achieved in Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, multiple-monitors, lubuntu

I have a laptop which I want to have connected to an external monitor 99% of the time. The other 1% I would use its screen. I want the laptop to be closed (usually) to save space, and to use external KB/mouse. The external monitor supports a higher resolution than the laptop screen, so I won't use screen duplication, and extended desktop is annoying when one of the monitors can't be viewed, so also out of the question.

Is there a simple way to enable the external only configuration, but that would switch to the internal monitor when the external monitor is disconnected, like regular Ubuntu/Windows/etc provide?

In addition/alternatively, What software does regular Ubuntu or other linux distros use to enable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably a Gnome or Unity feature which is absent from LXDE. You could probably write a `udev` rule to do this on monitor disconnect.

I have written a little script that will detect the monitors and extend accordingly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

xrandr | grep VGA | grep -w connected >/dev/null
echo $?
if [[ "$?" -lt 1 ]]
then
    notify-send "Extending desktop to VGA screen"
    xrandr --output DP-3 --auto --output VGA-0 --auto --right-of DP-3 --primary
else
    xrandr | grep DP-2 | grep connected >/dev/null
    if [[ "$?" -gt 0 ]]
    then
    notify-send "Extending desktop to DisplayPort screen"
    xrandr --output DP-3 --auto --output DP-2 --auto --right-of DP-3 --primary
    else
    notify-send "No known screens found"
    fi

fi
```

You need to have `xrandr` installed but you almost certainly do. You will also need to change the monitor names accordingly (in my case I switch between an external VGA and and external Display Port display). Run `xrandr` with your external screen connected to getthe right name or update your question with the output of `xrandr` and I can help you with it.

I have mapped this script to be run with a keyboard shortcut and simply run it whenever I connect or disconnect a screen.

Comment: Thanks! I also found this [github repository](https://github.com/codingtony/udev-monitor-hotplug) which I like better since there is no polling. I will accept your answer nevertheless, since it provides a solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [autorandr](https://github.com/phillipberndt/autorandr) to save both settings and let autorandr change the settings when you plug/unplug your screen. If it does not work automatically, use `autorandr -c` to force detection of the current setting.